# Predictive model for Turnover - Correlation or Survival Analysis

Tags: regression, probability, correlation, survival

Question 1 - I a working on developing a model to predict employee turnover. The variables that I have are age, tenure, job satisfaction, role clarity etc. Through research papers I have found the correlation coefficient for these variables but I am not sure on how to develop a model around it?? Some leads on how to go ahead with this??

Question 2 - Can these variable be used in survival analysis models like Cox??

Which technique would be better.

I am new to statistics but ready to learn :)

Comment: If some people are censored, that is they have not left yet, then you need survival analysis. If someone has been employed for (say) 5 years and has not left, you don't know their tenure, you only know that their tenure will be greater than 5 years.

Comment: Oh, something else. You might be interested in *why* they left. If some (for example) leaves due to ill health or death, you might want to treat that as censored, it's different from leaving because of job satisfaction or role clarity. Again, you need survival analysis, because if they died after 5 years, you don't know when they would have left, you just know it was more than 5 years. (You might consider retirement too.)